# Как сместить вправо path в svg не меняя координаты?

Tags: html, css, html5, svg, svg-animation

У меня есть svg файл, в котором рисунок смещен влево и не соответствует фону. Возможно ли как-то сместить пути с классом "paths" вправо и вниз, что бы рисунок был по центру? Я пробовал transform translate, но ничего не поменялось, хотя тот же translate в случае с анимацией работает

```html
<svg width="228" height="217" viewBox="0 0 228 217" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M209.585 96.2777L228 86L209.585 75.7223C204.411 33.1002 167.885 0 123.597 0C75.809 0 37.0002 38.5413 37.0002 86C37.0002 133.459 75.809 172 123.597 172C167.885 172 204.411 138.9 209.585 96.2777Z" fill="#FF4D59"/>
<path opacity="0.3" d="M197 89.6644C197 49.526 164.682 17 124.801 17C104.345 17 85.9511 25.4775 72.7147 39.1453C72.3709 39.4914 72.0271 39.8374 71.6833 40.1834C71.3394 40.5294 70.9956 40.8754 70.6518 41.2215C70.308 41.5675 69.9642 41.9135 69.6204 42.2595C69.2766 42.6055 68.9328 42.9516 68.589 43.2976C68.2452 43.6436 67.9014 43.9896 67.5576 44.3356C67.2138 44.6817 66.87 45.0277 66.5262 45.3737C66.1824 45.7197 65.8386 46.0657 65.4948 46.4118C65.151 46.7578 64.8072 47.1038 64.4634 47.4498C64.1195 47.7958 63.7757 48.1419 63.4319 48.4879C63.0881 48.8339 62.7443 49.1799 62.4005 49.526C62.0567 49.872 61.7129 50.218 61.3691 50.564C61.0253 50.91 60.6815 51.2561 60.3377 51.6021C59.9939 51.9481 59.6501 52.2941 59.3063 52.6401C58.9625 52.9862 58.6187 53.3322 58.2749 53.6782C57.9311 54.0242 57.5873 54.3702 57.2435 54.7163C56.8997 55.0623 56.5559 55.4083 56.212 55.7543C55.8682 56.1003 55.5244 56.4464 55.1806 56.7924C54.8368 57.1384 54.493 57.4844 54.1492 57.8305C53.8054 58.1765 53.4616 58.5225 53.1178 58.8685C52.774 59.2145 52.4302 59.5606 52.0864 59.9066C51.7426 60.2526 51.3988 60.5986 51.055 60.9446C50.7112 61.2907 50.3674 61.6367 50.0236 61.9827C49.6798 62.3287 49.336 62.6747 48.9921 63.0208C48.6483 63.3668 48.3045 63.7128 47.9607 64.0588C47.6169 64.4048 47.2731 64.7509 46.9293 65.0969C46.5855 65.4429 46.2417 65.7889 45.8979 66.1349C45.5541 66.481 45.2103 66.827 44.8665 67.173C44.5227 67.519 44.1789 67.8651 43.8351 68.2111C43.4913 68.5571 43.1475 68.9031 42.8037 69.2491C42.4599 69.5952 42.1161 69.9412 41.7723 70.2872C41.4284 70.6332 41.0846 70.9792 40.7408 71.3253C40.397 71.6713 40.0532 72.0173 39.7094 72.3633C39.3656 72.7093 39.0218 73.0554 38.678 73.4014C38.3342 73.7474 37.9904 74.0934 37.6466 74.4394C37.3028 74.7855 36.959 75.1315 36.6152 75.4775C36.2714 75.8235 35.9276 76.1696 35.5838 76.5156C35.24 76.8616 34.8962 77.2076 34.5524 77.5536C34.2086 77.8997 33.8647 78.2457 33.5209 78.5917C33.1771 78.9377 32.8333 79.2837 32.4895 79.6298C32.1457 79.9758 31.8019 80.3218 31.4581 80.6678C31.1143 81.0138 30.7705 81.3599 30.4267 81.7059C30.0829 82.0519 29.7391 82.3979 29.3953 82.7439C29.0515 83.09 28.7077 83.436 28.3639 83.782C28.0201 84.128 27.6763 84.4741 27.3325 84.8201C26.9887 85.1661 26.6449 85.5121 26.301 85.8581C25.9572 86.2042 25.6134 86.5502 25.2696 86.8962C24.9258 87.2422 24.582 87.5882 24.2382 87.9343C23.8944 88.2803 23.5506 88.6263 23.2068 88.9723C22.863 89.3183 22.5192 89.6644 22.1754 90.0104C21.8316 90.3564 21.4878 90.7024 21.144 91.0484C8.07941 105.927 0 124.266 0 144.336C0 184.474 32.3176 217 72.199 217C92.6553 217 111.049 208.523 124.113 194.855C124.457 194.509 124.801 194.163 125.145 193.817C125.489 193.471 125.832 193.125 126.176 192.779C126.52 192.433 126.864 192.087 127.208 191.74C127.551 191.394 127.895 191.048 128.239 190.702C128.583 190.356 128.927 190.01 129.271 189.664C129.614 189.318 129.958 188.972 130.302 188.626C130.646 188.28 130.99 187.934 131.333 187.588C131.677 187.242 132.021 186.896 132.365 186.55C132.709 186.204 133.052 185.858 133.396 185.512C133.74 185.166 134.084 184.82 134.428 184.474C134.771 184.128 135.115 183.782 135.459 183.436C135.803 183.09 136.147 182.744 136.49 182.398C136.834 182.052 137.178 181.706 137.522 181.36C137.866 181.014 138.209 180.668 138.553 180.322C138.897 179.976 139.241 179.63 139.585 179.284C139.928 178.938 140.272 178.592 140.616 178.246C140.96 177.9 141.304 177.554 141.647 177.208C141.991 176.862 142.335 176.516 142.679 176.17C143.023 175.824 143.367 175.478 143.71 175.132C144.054 174.785 144.398 174.439 144.742 174.093C145.086 173.747 145.429 173.401 145.773 173.055C146.117 172.709 146.461 172.363 146.805 172.017C147.148 171.671 147.492 171.325 147.836 170.979C148.18 170.633 148.524 170.287 148.867 169.941C149.211 169.595 149.555 169.249 149.899 168.903C150.243 168.557 150.586 168.211 150.93 167.865C151.274 167.519 151.618 167.173 151.962 166.827C152.305 166.481 152.649 166.135 152.993 165.789C153.337 165.443 153.681 165.097 154.024 164.751C154.368 164.405 154.712 164.059 155.056 163.713C155.4 163.367 155.743 163.021 156.087 162.675C156.431 162.329 156.775 161.983 157.119 161.637C157.462 161.291 157.806 160.945 158.15 160.599C158.494 160.253 158.838 159.907 159.182 159.561C159.525 159.215 159.869 158.869 160.213 158.523C160.557 158.176 160.901 157.83 161.244 157.484C161.588 157.138 161.932 156.792 162.276 156.446C162.62 156.1 162.963 155.754 163.307 155.408C163.651 155.062 163.995 154.716 164.339 154.37C164.682 154.024 165.026 153.678 165.37 153.332C165.714 152.986 166.058 152.64 166.401 152.294C166.745 151.948 167.089 151.602 167.433 151.256C167.777 150.91 168.12 150.564 168.464 150.218C168.808 149.872 169.152 149.526 169.496 149.18C169.839 148.834 170.183 148.488 170.527 148.142C170.871 147.796 171.215 147.45 171.558 147.104C171.902 146.758 172.246 146.412 172.59 146.066C172.934 145.72 173.277 145.374 173.621 145.028C173.965 144.682 174.309 144.336 174.653 143.99C174.997 143.644 175.34 143.298 175.684 142.952C188.749 128.073 197 109.907 197 89.6644Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<path d="M125 155C163.108 155 194 124.108 194 86C194 47.8924 163.108 17 125 17C86.8924 17 56 47.8924 56 86C56 124.108 86.8924 155 125 155Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
<path d="M125 150.528C160.638 150.528 189.528 121.638 189.528 86C189.528 50.3622 160.638 21.4722 125 21.4722C89.3622 21.4722 60.4722 50.3622 60.4722 86C60.4722 121.638 89.3622 150.528 125 150.528Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear)"/>
<path d="M125 143.82C156.933 143.82 182.82 117.933 182.82 86.0001C182.82 54.0673 156.933 28.1807 125 28.1807C93.0673 28.1807 67.1807 54.0673 67.1807 86.0001C67.1807 117.933 93.0673 143.82 125 143.82Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"/>

<path class= "paths"  d="M55.2165 37.4941C54.3932 37.4941 54.1188 37.976 54.1188 38.458C54.1188 39.9038 52.7466 41.1086 51.1 41.1086C49.4534 41.1086 48.0812 39.9038 48.0812 38.458C48.0812 37.0122 49.4534 35.8074 51.1 35.8074C51.9233 35.8074 52.1977 35.3254 52.1977 34.8435C52.1977 34.1206 51.6489 33.8797 51.1 33.8797C48.0812 33.8797 45.8857 36.0483 45.8857 38.458C45.8857 41.1086 48.3556 43.0363 51.1 43.0363C54.1188 43.0363 56.3143 40.8676 56.3143 38.458C56.3143 37.7351 55.7654 37.4941 55.2165 37.4941Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>
<path class= "paths"  d="M36.5103 12.8193C40.0799 12.8193 42.7571 9.9058 42.7571 6.40964C42.7571 2.91347 39.7824 0 36.5103 0C32.9406 0 30.2634 2.91347 30.2634 6.40964C29.9659 10.1972 32.9406 12.8193 36.5103 12.8193ZM36.5103 2.91347C38.5926 2.91347 40.3774 4.66155 40.3774 6.70098C40.3774 8.74042 38.5926 10.4885 36.5103 10.4885C34.428 10.4885 32.6432 8.74042 32.6432 6.70098C32.6432 4.37021 34.428 2.91347 36.5103 2.91347Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>
<path class= "paths" d="M68.6325 35.0874H66.1368C64.265 30.4507 61.1453 26.0866 56.7778 23.0864V12.9946C56.7778 12.4491 56.1538 11.9036 55.5299 11.9036C51.1624 11.9036 47.1068 14.0856 45.235 17.3586C42.1154 16.5404 39.6197 16.2676 36.188 16.2676C24.0214 16.2676 13.4145 22.2681 8.11111 30.7234C7.48718 31.2689 6.86325 31.5417 5.92735 31.5417C4.05556 31.5417 2.80769 30.1779 2.80769 28.8141C2.80769 27.7231 3.74359 26.3594 4.99145 26.0866C5.61539 25.8139 5.92735 25.2684 5.92735 24.4501C5.61538 23.9046 4.67949 23.6319 4.05556 23.9046C1.55983 24.7229 0 26.6321 0 28.8141C0 31.5417 2.80769 33.9964 5.92735 33.9964H6.55128C5.30342 36.9967 4.36752 40.2697 4.36752 43.8154C4.36752 51.9979 8.73504 59.9077 16.2222 65.6355V71.9087C16.2222 74.3635 19.0299 76 21.5256 76H24.6453C27.141 76 28.7009 74.3635 28.7009 71.9087V70.545C33.3803 71.3632 38.6838 71.3632 43.3632 70.545V71.9087C43.3632 74.0907 45.547 76 48.0427 76H50.8504C53.3462 76 55.5299 74.0907 55.5299 71.9087V65.6355C60.5214 62.3625 64.265 57.9985 66.1368 52.5434H68.6325C70.8162 52.5434 73 50.6342 73 48.7249V38.3604C72.688 36.4512 70.5043 35.0874 68.6325 35.0874ZM70.1923 48.7249C70.1923 49.5432 69.2564 50.3614 68.6325 50.3614H65.8248C64.5769 50.3614 63.953 50.9069 63.641 51.4524C61.7692 56.6347 58.3376 60.9987 53.3462 63.999C53.0342 64.2717 52.7222 64.5445 52.7222 64.8172V71.9087C52.7222 72.9997 51.7863 73.818 50.8504 73.818H48.0427C47.1068 73.818 46.1709 72.9997 46.1709 71.9087V69.1812C46.1709 68.9085 46.1709 68.363 45.547 68.363C45.235 68.0902 44.6111 68.0902 44.2991 68.0902C41.8034 68.6357 38.6838 68.9085 35.8761 68.9085C33.0684 68.9085 30.2607 68.6357 27.453 68.0902C27.141 68.0902 26.5171 68.0902 26.2051 68.363C25.8932 68.6357 25.5812 68.9085 25.5812 69.1812V71.9087C25.5812 72.4542 25.5812 73.818 24.3333 73.818H21.8376C20.5897 73.818 19.3419 72.9997 19.3419 71.9087V65.09C19.3419 64.8172 19.3419 64.2717 18.7179 64.2717C11.5427 59.0895 7.17521 51.4524 7.17521 44.0882C7.17521 39.9969 8.42308 35.9057 10.2949 32.3599C10.2949 32.0872 10.6068 32.0872 10.9188 31.8144C11.2308 31.8144 11.2308 31.5417 11.2308 31.2689C16.2222 23.9046 25.5812 18.7224 36.188 18.7224C38.9957 18.7224 41.4915 18.7224 44.2991 19.5406C44.2991 20.3589 43.9872 20.9044 43.9872 21.7226C43.9872 22.5409 44.6111 22.8136 45.235 22.8136C46.1709 22.8136 46.7949 22.2681 46.7949 21.7226C46.7949 17.9041 49.9145 14.9039 54.2821 14.3584V23.3591C54.2821 23.6319 54.594 24.1774 54.906 24.1774C54.906 24.1774 54.906 24.4501 55.218 24.7229C59.2735 27.7231 62.3932 31.8144 63.953 36.4512C63.953 36.9967 64.5769 37.5422 66.1368 37.5422H68.6325C69.5684 37.5422 70.1923 38.0877 70.1923 38.6332V48.7249Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>


<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="27.1728" y1="188.783" x2="160.29" y2="56.5178" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.12661" stop-opacity="0.02"/>
<stop offset="0.479913" stop-opacity="0.3"/>
<stop offset="0.9" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="27.8314" y1="187.736" x2="153.273" y2="56.4691" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.0937052" stop-color="#E1DED7"/>
<stop offset="0.3964" stop-color="#F0EFEB"/>
<stop offset="0.6991" stop-color="#F9F9F7"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="34.1127" y1="-9.01976" x2="151.447" y2="113.648" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.0937052" stop-color="#E1DED7"/>
<stop offset="0.3964" stop-color="#F0EFEB"/>
<stop offset="0.6991" stop-color="#F9F9F7"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="188.475" y1="171.24" x2="98.1623" y2="49.947" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.1324" stop-color="#E4E2DB"/>
<stop offset="0.4221" stop-color="#F3F2EF"/>
<stop offset="0.7119" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white"/>
</linearGradient>
<clipPath id="clip0">
<rect width="68" height="56" fill="white" transform="translate(90 61)"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<style type="text/css">
.paths { animation: anim  linear forwards 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   z-index: 999;
}
@keyframes anim {
 from {
  transform: translateY(0%);}

 25%{
 transform: translateY(3%);}
  
 50% {
  transform: translateY(0%);}
  75% {
   transform: translateY(-3%);}
  
 to {
  transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 }
 </style>
</svg>
```

Comment: добавьте все в группу и ей translate

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо! Можете продублировать это в ответ, что бы я мог отметить его как верный?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поместить необходимые элементы в группу и ее уже подвинуть при помощи `transform=translate()`

```
<g transform=translate(100,100)>
   ...
</g>
```

```html
<svg width="228" height="217" viewBox="0 0 228 217" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


<path d="M209.585 96.2777L228 86L209.585 75.7223C204.411 33.1002 167.885 0 123.597 0C75.809 0 37.0002 38.5413 37.0002 86C37.0002 133.459 75.809 172 123.597 172C167.885 172 204.411 138.9 209.585 96.2777Z" fill="#FF4D59"/>
<path opacity="0.3" d="M197 89.6644C197 49.526 164.682 17 124.801 17C104.345 17 85.9511 25.4775 72.7147 39.1453C72.3709 39.4914 72.0271 39.8374 71.6833 40.1834C71.3394 40.5294 70.9956 40.8754 70.6518 41.2215C70.308 41.5675 69.9642 41.9135 69.6204 42.2595C69.2766 42.6055 68.9328 42.9516 68.589 43.2976C68.2452 43.6436 67.9014 43.9896 67.5576 44.3356C67.2138 44.6817 66.87 45.0277 66.5262 45.3737C66.1824 45.7197 65.8386 46.0657 65.4948 46.4118C65.151 46.7578 64.8072 47.1038 64.4634 47.4498C64.1195 47.7958 63.7757 48.1419 63.4319 48.4879C63.0881 48.8339 62.7443 49.1799 62.4005 49.526C62.0567 49.872 61.7129 50.218 61.3691 50.564C61.0253 50.91 60.6815 51.2561 60.3377 51.6021C59.9939 51.9481 59.6501 52.2941 59.3063 52.6401C58.9625 52.9862 58.6187 53.3322 58.2749 53.6782C57.9311 54.0242 57.5873 54.3702 57.2435 54.7163C56.8997 55.0623 56.5559 55.4083 56.212 55.7543C55.8682 56.1003 55.5244 56.4464 55.1806 56.7924C54.8368 57.1384 54.493 57.4844 54.1492 57.8305C53.8054 58.1765 53.4616 58.5225 53.1178 58.8685C52.774 59.2145 52.4302 59.5606 52.0864 59.9066C51.7426 60.2526 51.3988 60.5986 51.055 60.9446C50.7112 61.2907 50.3674 61.6367 50.0236 61.9827C49.6798 62.3287 49.336 62.6747 48.9921 63.0208C48.6483 63.3668 48.3045 63.7128 47.9607 64.0588C47.6169 64.4048 47.2731 64.7509 46.9293 65.0969C46.5855 65.4429 46.2417 65.7889 45.8979 66.1349C45.5541 66.481 45.2103 66.827 44.8665 67.173C44.5227 67.519 44.1789 67.8651 43.8351 68.2111C43.4913 68.5571 43.1475 68.9031 42.8037 69.2491C42.4599 69.5952 42.1161 69.9412 41.7723 70.2872C41.4284 70.6332 41.0846 70.9792 40.7408 71.3253C40.397 71.6713 40.0532 72.0173 39.7094 72.3633C39.3656 72.7093 39.0218 73.0554 38.678 73.4014C38.3342 73.7474 37.9904 74.0934 37.6466 74.4394C37.3028 74.7855 36.959 75.1315 36.6152 75.4775C36.2714 75.8235 35.9276 76.1696 35.5838 76.5156C35.24 76.8616 34.8962 77.2076 34.5524 77.5536C34.2086 77.8997 33.8647 78.2457 33.5209 78.5917C33.1771 78.9377 32.8333 79.2837 32.4895 79.6298C32.1457 79.9758 31.8019 80.3218 31.4581 80.6678C31.1143 81.0138 30.7705 81.3599 30.4267 81.7059C30.0829 82.0519 29.7391 82.3979 29.3953 82.7439C29.0515 83.09 28.7077 83.436 28.3639 83.782C28.0201 84.128 27.6763 84.4741 27.3325 84.8201C26.9887 85.1661 26.6449 85.5121 26.301 85.8581C25.9572 86.2042 25.6134 86.5502 25.2696 86.8962C24.9258 87.2422 24.582 87.5882 24.2382 87.9343C23.8944 88.2803 23.5506 88.6263 23.2068 88.9723C22.863 89.3183 22.5192 89.6644 22.1754 90.0104C21.8316 90.3564 21.4878 90.7024 21.144 91.0484C8.07941 105.927 0 124.266 0 144.336C0 184.474 32.3176 217 72.199 217C92.6553 217 111.049 208.523 124.113 194.855C124.457 194.509 124.801 194.163 125.145 193.817C125.489 193.471 125.832 193.125 126.176 192.779C126.52 192.433 126.864 192.087 127.208 191.74C127.551 191.394 127.895 191.048 128.239 190.702C128.583 190.356 128.927 190.01 129.271 189.664C129.614 189.318 129.958 188.972 130.302 188.626C130.646 188.28 130.99 187.934 131.333 187.588C131.677 187.242 132.021 186.896 132.365 186.55C132.709 186.204 133.052 185.858 133.396 185.512C133.74 185.166 134.084 184.82 134.428 184.474C134.771 184.128 135.115 183.782 135.459 183.436C135.803 183.09 136.147 182.744 136.49 182.398C136.834 182.052 137.178 181.706 137.522 181.36C137.866 181.014 138.209 180.668 138.553 180.322C138.897 179.976 139.241 179.63 139.585 179.284C139.928 178.938 140.272 178.592 140.616 178.246C140.96 177.9 141.304 177.554 141.647 177.208C141.991 176.862 142.335 176.516 142.679 176.17C143.023 175.824 143.367 175.478 143.71 175.132C144.054 174.785 144.398 174.439 144.742 174.093C145.086 173.747 145.429 173.401 145.773 173.055C146.117 172.709 146.461 172.363 146.805 172.017C147.148 171.671 147.492 171.325 147.836 170.979C148.18 170.633 148.524 170.287 148.867 169.941C149.211 169.595 149.555 169.249 149.899 168.903C150.243 168.557 150.586 168.211 150.93 167.865C151.274 167.519 151.618 167.173 151.962 166.827C152.305 166.481 152.649 166.135 152.993 165.789C153.337 165.443 153.681 165.097 154.024 164.751C154.368 164.405 154.712 164.059 155.056 163.713C155.4 163.367 155.743 163.021 156.087 162.675C156.431 162.329 156.775 161.983 157.119 161.637C157.462 161.291 157.806 160.945 158.15 160.599C158.494 160.253 158.838 159.907 159.182 159.561C159.525 159.215 159.869 158.869 160.213 158.523C160.557 158.176 160.901 157.83 161.244 157.484C161.588 157.138 161.932 156.792 162.276 156.446C162.62 156.1 162.963 155.754 163.307 155.408C163.651 155.062 163.995 154.716 164.339 154.37C164.682 154.024 165.026 153.678 165.37 153.332C165.714 152.986 166.058 152.64 166.401 152.294C166.745 151.948 167.089 151.602 167.433 151.256C167.777 150.91 168.12 150.564 168.464 150.218C168.808 149.872 169.152 149.526 169.496 149.18C169.839 148.834 170.183 148.488 170.527 148.142C170.871 147.796 171.215 147.45 171.558 147.104C171.902 146.758 172.246 146.412 172.59 146.066C172.934 145.72 173.277 145.374 173.621 145.028C173.965 144.682 174.309 144.336 174.653 143.99C174.997 143.644 175.34 143.298 175.684 142.952C188.749 128.073 197 109.907 197 89.6644Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>

















<path d="M125 155C163.108 155 194 124.108 194 86C194 47.8924 163.108 17 125 17C86.8924 17 56 47.8924 56 86C56 124.108 86.8924 155 125 155Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
<path d="M125 150.528C160.638 150.528 189.528 121.638 189.528 86C189.528 50.3622 160.638 21.4722 125 21.4722C89.3622 21.4722 60.4722 50.3622 60.4722 86C60.4722 121.638 89.3622 150.528 125 150.528Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear)"/>

<path d="M125 143.82C156.933 143.82 182.82 117.933 182.82 86.0001C182.82 54.0673 156.933 28.1807 125 28.1807C93.0673 28.1807 67.1807 54.0673 67.1807 86.0001C67.1807 117.933 93.0673 143.82 125 143.82Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"/>

<g transform=translate(90,50)>

<path class= "paths"  d="M55.2165 37.4941C54.3932 37.4941 54.1188 37.976 54.1188 38.458C54.1188 39.9038 52.7466 41.1086 51.1 41.1086C49.4534 41.1086 48.0812 39.9038 48.0812 38.458C48.0812 37.0122 49.4534 35.8074 51.1 35.8074C51.9233 35.8074 52.1977 35.3254 52.1977 34.8435C52.1977 34.1206 51.6489 33.8797 51.1 33.8797C48.0812 33.8797 45.8857 36.0483 45.8857 38.458C45.8857 41.1086 48.3556 43.0363 51.1 43.0363C54.1188 43.0363 56.3143 40.8676 56.3143 38.458C56.3143 37.7351 55.7654 37.4941 55.2165 37.4941Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>
<path class= "paths"  d="M36.5103 12.8193C40.0799 12.8193 42.7571 9.9058 42.7571 6.40964C42.7571 2.91347 39.7824 0 36.5103 0C32.9406 0 30.2634 2.91347 30.2634 6.40964C29.9659 10.1972 32.9406 12.8193 36.5103 12.8193ZM36.5103 2.91347C38.5926 2.91347 40.3774 4.66155 40.3774 6.70098C40.3774 8.74042 38.5926 10.4885 36.5103 10.4885C34.428 10.4885 32.6432 8.74042 32.6432 6.70098C32.6432 4.37021 34.428 2.91347 36.5103 2.91347Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>
<path class= "paths" d="M68.6325 35.0874H66.1368C64.265 30.4507 61.1453 26.0866 56.7778 23.0864V12.9946C56.7778 12.4491 56.1538 11.9036 55.5299 11.9036C51.1624 11.9036 47.1068 14.0856 45.235 17.3586C42.1154 16.5404 39.6197 16.2676 36.188 16.2676C24.0214 16.2676 13.4145 22.2681 8.11111 30.7234C7.48718 31.2689 6.86325 31.5417 5.92735 31.5417C4.05556 31.5417 2.80769 30.1779 2.80769 28.8141C2.80769 27.7231 3.74359 26.3594 4.99145 26.0866C5.61539 25.8139 5.92735 25.2684 5.92735 24.4501C5.61538 23.9046 4.67949 23.6319 4.05556 23.9046C1.55983 24.7229 0 26.6321 0 28.8141C0 31.5417 2.80769 33.9964 5.92735 33.9964H6.55128C5.30342 36.9967 4.36752 40.2697 4.36752 43.8154C4.36752 51.9979 8.73504 59.9077 16.2222 65.6355V71.9087C16.2222 74.3635 19.0299 76 21.5256 76H24.6453C27.141 76 28.7009 74.3635 28.7009 71.9087V70.545C33.3803 71.3632 38.6838 71.3632 43.3632 70.545V71.9087C43.3632 74.0907 45.547 76 48.0427 76H50.8504C53.3462 76 55.5299 74.0907 55.5299 71.9087V65.6355C60.5214 62.3625 64.265 57.9985 66.1368 52.5434H68.6325C70.8162 52.5434 73 50.6342 73 48.7249V38.3604C72.688 36.4512 70.5043 35.0874 68.6325 35.0874ZM70.1923 48.7249C70.1923 49.5432 69.2564 50.3614 68.6325 50.3614H65.8248C64.5769 50.3614 63.953 50.9069 63.641 51.4524C61.7692 56.6347 58.3376 60.9987 53.3462 63.999C53.0342 64.2717 52.7222 64.5445 52.7222 64.8172V71.9087C52.7222 72.9997 51.7863 73.818 50.8504 73.818H48.0427C47.1068 73.818 46.1709 72.9997 46.1709 71.9087V69.1812C46.1709 68.9085 46.1709 68.363 45.547 68.363C45.235 68.0902 44.6111 68.0902 44.2991 68.0902C41.8034 68.6357 38.6838 68.9085 35.8761 68.9085C33.0684 68.9085 30.2607 68.6357 27.453 68.0902C27.141 68.0902 26.5171 68.0902 26.2051 68.363C25.8932 68.6357 25.5812 68.9085 25.5812 69.1812V71.9087C25.5812 72.4542 25.5812 73.818 24.3333 73.818H21.8376C20.5897 73.818 19.3419 72.9997 19.3419 71.9087V65.09C19.3419 64.8172 19.3419 64.2717 18.7179 64.2717C11.5427 59.0895 7.17521 51.4524 7.17521 44.0882C7.17521 39.9969 8.42308 35.9057 10.2949 32.3599C10.2949 32.0872 10.6068 32.0872 10.9188 31.8144C11.2308 31.8144 11.2308 31.5417 11.2308 31.2689C16.2222 23.9046 25.5812 18.7224 36.188 18.7224C38.9957 18.7224 41.4915 18.7224 44.2991 19.5406C44.2991 20.3589 43.9872 20.9044 43.9872 21.7226C43.9872 22.5409 44.6111 22.8136 45.235 22.8136C46.1709 22.8136 46.7949 22.2681 46.7949 21.7226C46.7949 17.9041 49.9145 14.9039 54.2821 14.3584V23.3591C54.2821 23.6319 54.594 24.1774 54.906 24.1774C54.906 24.1774 54.906 24.4501 55.218 24.7229C59.2735 27.7231 62.3932 31.8144 63.953 36.4512C63.953 36.9967 64.5769 37.5422 66.1368 37.5422H68.6325C69.5684 37.5422 70.1923 38.0877 70.1923 38.6332V48.7249Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>

</g>

<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="27.1728" y1="188.783" x2="160.29" y2="56.5178" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.12661" stop-opacity="0.02"/>
<stop offset="0.479913" stop-opacity="0.3"/>
<stop offset="0.9" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="27.8314" y1="187.736" x2="153.273" y2="56.4691" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.0937052" stop-color="#E1DED7"/>
<stop offset="0.3964" stop-color="#F0EFEB"/>
<stop offset="0.6991" stop-color="#F9F9F7"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="34.1127" y1="-9.01976" x2="151.447" y2="113.648" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.0937052" stop-color="#E1DED7"/>
<stop offset="0.3964" stop-color="#F0EFEB"/>
<stop offset="0.6991" stop-color="#F9F9F7"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="188.475" y1="171.24" x2="98.1623" y2="49.947" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.1324" stop-color="#E4E2DB"/>
<stop offset="0.4221" stop-color="#F3F2EF"/>
<stop offset="0.7119" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white"/>
</linearGradient>
<clipPath id="clip0">
<rect width="68" height="56" fill="white" transform="translate(90 61)"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<style type="text/css">
.paths { animation: anim  linear forwards 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   z-index: 999;
}
@keyframes anim {
 from {
  transform: translateY(0%);}

 25%{
 transform: translateY(3%);}
  
 50% {
  transform: translateY(0%);}
  75% {
   transform: translateY(-3%);}
  
 to {
  transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 }
 </style>
</svg>
```

```html
<svg width="228" height="217" viewBox="0 0 228 217" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M209.585 96.2777L228 86L209.585 75.7223C204.411 33.1002 167.885 0 123.597 0C75.809 0 37.0002 38.5413 37.0002 86C37.0002 133.459 75.809 172 123.597 172C167.885 172 204.411 138.9 209.585 96.2777Z" fill="#FF4D59"/>
<path opacity="0.3" d="M197 89.6644C197 49.526 164.682 17 124.801 17C104.345 17 85.9511 25.4775 72.7147 39.1453C72.3709 39.4914 72.0271 39.8374 71.6833 40.1834C71.3394 40.5294 70.9956 40.8754 70.6518 41.2215C70.308 41.5675 69.9642 41.9135 69.6204 42.2595C69.2766 42.6055 68.9328 42.9516 68.589 43.2976C68.2452 43.6436 67.9014 43.9896 67.5576 44.3356C67.2138 44.6817 66.87 45.0277 66.5262 45.3737C66.1824 45.7197 65.8386 46.0657 65.4948 46.4118C65.151 46.7578 64.8072 47.1038 64.4634 47.4498C64.1195 47.7958 63.7757 48.1419 63.4319 48.4879C63.0881 48.8339 62.7443 49.1799 62.4005 49.526C62.0567 49.872 61.7129 50.218 61.3691 50.564C61.0253 50.91 60.6815 51.2561 60.3377 51.6021C59.9939 51.9481 59.6501 52.2941 59.3063 52.6401C58.9625 52.9862 58.6187 53.3322 58.2749 53.6782C57.9311 54.0242 57.5873 54.3702 57.2435 54.7163C56.8997 55.0623 56.5559 55.4083 56.212 55.7543C55.8682 56.1003 55.5244 56.4464 55.1806 56.7924C54.8368 57.1384 54.493 57.4844 54.1492 57.8305C53.8054 58.1765 53.4616 58.5225 53.1178 58.8685C52.774 59.2145 52.4302 59.5606 52.0864 59.9066C51.7426 60.2526 51.3988 60.5986 51.055 60.9446C50.7112 61.2907 50.3674 61.6367 50.0236 61.9827C49.6798 62.3287 49.336 62.6747 48.9921 63.0208C48.6483 63.3668 48.3045 63.7128 47.9607 64.0588C47.6169 64.4048 47.2731 64.7509 46.9293 65.0969C46.5855 65.4429 46.2417 65.7889 45.8979 66.1349C45.5541 66.481 45.2103 66.827 44.8665 67.173C44.5227 67.519 44.1789 67.8651 43.8351 68.2111C43.4913 68.5571 43.1475 68.9031 42.8037 69.2491C42.4599 69.5952 42.1161 69.9412 41.7723 70.2872C41.4284 70.6332 41.0846 70.9792 40.7408 71.3253C40.397 71.6713 40.0532 72.0173 39.7094 72.3633C39.3656 72.7093 39.0218 73.0554 38.678 73.4014C38.3342 73.7474 37.9904 74.0934 37.6466 74.4394C37.3028 74.7855 36.959 75.1315 36.6152 75.4775C36.2714 75.8235 35.9276 76.1696 35.5838 76.5156C35.24 76.8616 34.8962 77.2076 34.5524 77.5536C34.2086 77.8997 33.8647 78.2457 33.5209 78.5917C33.1771 78.9377 32.8333 79.2837 32.4895 79.6298C32.1457 79.9758 31.8019 80.3218 31.4581 80.6678C31.1143 81.0138 30.7705 81.3599 30.4267 81.7059C30.0829 82.0519 29.7391 82.3979 29.3953 82.7439C29.0515 83.09 28.7077 83.436 28.3639 83.782C28.0201 84.128 27.6763 84.4741 27.3325 84.8201C26.9887 85.1661 26.6449 85.5121 26.301 85.8581C25.9572 86.2042 25.6134 86.5502 25.2696 86.8962C24.9258 87.2422 24.582 87.5882 24.2382 87.9343C23.8944 88.2803 23.5506 88.6263 23.2068 88.9723C22.863 89.3183 22.5192 89.6644 22.1754 90.0104C21.8316 90.3564 21.4878 90.7024 21.144 91.0484C8.07941 105.927 0 124.266 0 144.336C0 184.474 32.3176 217 72.199 217C92.6553 217 111.049 208.523 124.113 194.855C124.457 194.509 124.801 194.163 125.145 193.817C125.489 193.471 125.832 193.125 126.176 192.779C126.52 192.433 126.864 192.087 127.208 191.74C127.551 191.394 127.895 191.048 128.239 190.702C128.583 190.356 128.927 190.01 129.271 189.664C129.614 189.318 129.958 188.972 130.302 188.626C130.646 188.28 130.99 187.934 131.333 187.588C131.677 187.242 132.021 186.896 132.365 186.55C132.709 186.204 133.052 185.858 133.396 185.512C133.74 185.166 134.084 184.82 134.428 184.474C134.771 184.128 135.115 183.782 135.459 183.436C135.803 183.09 136.147 182.744 136.49 182.398C136.834 182.052 137.178 181.706 137.522 181.36C137.866 181.014 138.209 180.668 138.553 180.322C138.897 179.976 139.241 179.63 139.585 179.284C139.928 178.938 140.272 178.592 140.616 178.246C140.96 177.9 141.304 177.554 141.647 177.208C141.991 176.862 142.335 176.516 142.679 176.17C143.023 175.824 143.367 175.478 143.71 175.132C144.054 174.785 144.398 174.439 144.742 174.093C145.086 173.747 145.429 173.401 145.773 173.055C146.117 172.709 146.461 172.363 146.805 172.017C147.148 171.671 147.492 171.325 147.836 170.979C148.18 170.633 148.524 170.287 148.867 169.941C149.211 169.595 149.555 169.249 149.899 168.903C150.243 168.557 150.586 168.211 150.93 167.865C151.274 167.519 151.618 167.173 151.962 166.827C152.305 166.481 152.649 166.135 152.993 165.789C153.337 165.443 153.681 165.097 154.024 164.751C154.368 164.405 154.712 164.059 155.056 163.713C155.4 163.367 155.743 163.021 156.087 162.675C156.431 162.329 156.775 161.983 157.119 161.637C157.462 161.291 157.806 160.945 158.15 160.599C158.494 160.253 158.838 159.907 159.182 159.561C159.525 159.215 159.869 158.869 160.213 158.523C160.557 158.176 160.901 157.83 161.244 157.484C161.588 157.138 161.932 156.792 162.276 156.446C162.62 156.1 162.963 155.754 163.307 155.408C163.651 155.062 163.995 154.716 164.339 154.37C164.682 154.024 165.026 153.678 165.37 153.332C165.714 152.986 166.058 152.64 166.401 152.294C166.745 151.948 167.089 151.602 167.433 151.256C167.777 150.91 168.12 150.564 168.464 150.218C168.808 149.872 169.152 149.526 169.496 149.18C169.839 148.834 170.183 148.488 170.527 148.142C170.871 147.796 171.215 147.45 171.558 147.104C171.902 146.758 172.246 146.412 172.59 146.066C172.934 145.72 173.277 145.374 173.621 145.028C173.965 144.682 174.309 144.336 174.653 143.99C174.997 143.644 175.34 143.298 175.684 142.952C188.749 128.073 197 109.907 197 89.6644Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
















<path d="M125 155C163.108 155 194 124.108 194 86C194 47.8924 163.108 17 125 17C86.8924 17 56 47.8924 56 86C56 124.108 86.8924 155 125 155Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
<path d="M125 150.528C160.638 150.528 189.528 121.638 189.528 86C189.528 50.3622 160.638 21.4722 125 21.4722C89.3622 21.4722 60.4722 50.3622 60.4722 86C60.4722 121.638 89.3622 150.528 125 150.528Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear)"/>
<path d="M125 143.82C156.933 143.82 182.82 117.933 182.82 86.0001C182.82 54.0673 156.933 28.1807 125 28.1807C93.0673 28.1807 67.1807 54.0673 67.1807 86.0001C67.1807 117.933 93.0673 143.82 125 143.82Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"/>

<g transform=translate(90,48)>

<path class= "paths"  d="M55.2165 37.4941C54.3932 37.4941 54.1188 37.976 54.1188 38.458C54.1188 39.9038 52.7466 41.1086 51.1 41.1086C49.4534 41.1086 48.0812 39.9038 48.0812 38.458C48.0812 37.0122 49.4534 35.8074 51.1 35.8074C51.9233 35.8074 52.1977 35.3254 52.1977 34.8435C52.1977 34.1206 51.6489 33.8797 51.1 33.8797C48.0812 33.8797 45.8857 36.0483 45.8857 38.458C45.8857 41.1086 48.3556 43.0363 51.1 43.0363C54.1188 43.0363 56.3143 40.8676 56.3143 38.458C56.3143 37.7351 55.7654 37.4941 55.2165 37.4941Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>
<path class= "paths"  d="M36.5103 12.8193C40.0799 12.8193 42.7571 9.9058 42.7571 6.40964C42.7571 2.91347 39.7824 0 36.5103 0C32.9406 0 30.2634 2.91347 30.2634 6.40964C29.9659 10.1972 32.9406 12.8193 36.5103 12.8193ZM36.5103 2.91347C38.5926 2.91347 40.3774 4.66155 40.3774 6.70098C40.3774 8.74042 38.5926 10.4885 36.5103 10.4885C34.428 10.4885 32.6432 8.74042 32.6432 6.70098C32.6432 4.37021 34.428 2.91347 36.5103 2.91347Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>
<path class= "paths" d="M68.6325 35.0874H66.1368C64.265 30.4507 61.1453 26.0866 56.7778 23.0864V12.9946C56.7778 12.4491 56.1538 11.9036 55.5299 11.9036C51.1624 11.9036 47.1068 14.0856 45.235 17.3586C42.1154 16.5404 39.6197 16.2676 36.188 16.2676C24.0214 16.2676 13.4145 22.2681 8.11111 30.7234C7.48718 31.2689 6.86325 31.5417 5.92735 31.5417C4.05556 31.5417 2.80769 30.1779 2.80769 28.8141C2.80769 27.7231 3.74359 26.3594 4.99145 26.0866C5.61539 25.8139 5.92735 25.2684 5.92735 24.4501C5.61538 23.9046 4.67949 23.6319 4.05556 23.9046C1.55983 24.7229 0 26.6321 0 28.8141C0 31.5417 2.80769 33.9964 5.92735 33.9964H6.55128C5.30342 36.9967 4.36752 40.2697 4.36752 43.8154C4.36752 51.9979 8.73504 59.9077 16.2222 65.6355V71.9087C16.2222 74.3635 19.0299 76 21.5256 76H24.6453C27.141 76 28.7009 74.3635 28.7009 71.9087V70.545C33.3803 71.3632 38.6838 71.3632 43.3632 70.545V71.9087C43.3632 74.0907 45.547 76 48.0427 76H50.8504C53.3462 76 55.5299 74.0907 55.5299 71.9087V65.6355C60.5214 62.3625 64.265 57.9985 66.1368 52.5434H68.6325C70.8162 52.5434 73 50.6342 73 48.7249V38.3604C72.688 36.4512 70.5043 35.0874 68.6325 35.0874ZM70.1923 48.7249C70.1923 49.5432 69.2564 50.3614 68.6325 50.3614H65.8248C64.5769 50.3614 63.953 50.9069 63.641 51.4524C61.7692 56.6347 58.3376 60.9987 53.3462 63.999C53.0342 64.2717 52.7222 64.5445 52.7222 64.8172V71.9087C52.7222 72.9997 51.7863 73.818 50.8504 73.818H48.0427C47.1068 73.818 46.1709 72.9997 46.1709 71.9087V69.1812C46.1709 68.9085 46.1709 68.363 45.547 68.363C45.235 68.0902 44.6111 68.0902 44.2991 68.0902C41.8034 68.6357 38.6838 68.9085 35.8761 68.9085C33.0684 68.9085 30.2607 68.6357 27.453 68.0902C27.141 68.0902 26.5171 68.0902 26.2051 68.363C25.8932 68.6357 25.5812 68.9085 25.5812 69.1812V71.9087C25.5812 72.4542 25.5812 73.818 24.3333 73.818H21.8376C20.5897 73.818 19.3419 72.9997 19.3419 71.9087V65.09C19.3419 64.8172 19.3419 64.2717 18.7179 64.2717C11.5427 59.0895 7.17521 51.4524 7.17521 44.0882C7.17521 39.9969 8.42308 35.9057 10.2949 32.3599C10.2949 32.0872 10.6068 32.0872 10.9188 31.8144C11.2308 31.8144 11.2308 31.5417 11.2308 31.2689C16.2222 23.9046 25.5812 18.7224 36.188 18.7224C38.9957 18.7224 41.4915 18.7224 44.2991 19.5406C44.2991 20.3589 43.9872 20.9044 43.9872 21.7226C43.9872 22.5409 44.6111 22.8136 45.235 22.8136C46.1709 22.8136 46.7949 22.2681 46.7949 21.7226C46.7949 17.9041 49.9145 14.9039 54.2821 14.3584V23.3591C54.2821 23.6319 54.594 24.1774 54.906 24.1774C54.906 24.1774 54.906 24.4501 55.218 24.7229C59.2735 27.7231 62.3932 31.8144 63.953 36.4512C63.953 36.9967 64.5769 37.5422 66.1368 37.5422H68.6325C69.5684 37.5422 70.1923 38.0877 70.1923 38.6332V48.7249Z" fill="#A7AAB7"/>

</g>

<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="27.1728" y1="188.783" x2="160.29" y2="56.5178" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.12661" stop-opacity="0.02"/>
<stop offset="0.479913" stop-opacity="0.3"/>
<stop offset="0.9" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="27.8314" y1="187.736" x2="153.273" y2="56.4691" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.0937052" stop-color="#E1DED7"/>
<stop offset="0.3964" stop-color="#F0EFEB"/>
<stop offset="0.6991" stop-color="#F9F9F7"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="34.1127" y1="-9.01976" x2="151.447" y2="113.648" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.0937052" stop-color="#E1DED7"/>
<stop offset="0.3964" stop-color="#F0EFEB"/>
<stop offset="0.6991" stop-color="#F9F9F7"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="188.475" y1="171.24" x2="98.1623" y2="49.947" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DBD8CF"/>
<stop offset="0.1324" stop-color="#E4E2DB"/>
<stop offset="0.4221" stop-color="#F3F2EF"/>
<stop offset="0.7119" stop-color="#FCFCFB"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white"/>
</linearGradient>
<clipPath id="clip0">
<rect width="68" height="56" fill="white" transform="translate(90 61)"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<style type="text/css">
.paths { animation: anim  linear forwards 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   z-index: 999;
}
@keyframes anim {
 from {
  transform: translateY(0%);}

 25%{
 transform: translateY(3%);}
  
 50% {
  transform: translateY(0%);}
  75% {
   transform: translateY(-3%);}
  
 to {
  transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 }
 </style>
</svg>
```